# Sort array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => something
            [type] => first_type
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [key_1] => something_else
           [type] => first_type
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => something_else_3
            [type] => second_type
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key_1] => something_else_4
            [type] => second_type
        )
)
```

I have to sort by type value in a pattern like this:

```
first_type
second_type
first_type
second_type
```

My questions is, how can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you'll have to write this yourself; the fact that `[type]` is nested in it's own array means the standard PHP functions are going to find this tricky, although you should try using `sort()` and friends to see what they spit out.

Comment: You should first of all become more clear of your sort pattern. I don't see any even you said there is one. So what is the specification of your sorting?

Comment: Let's say I have the type key and the values can be 1 or 2. I need to sort it like this: 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I got it to work:

```
function filter_by_value($array, $index, $value) { 
    if(is_array($array) && count($array) > 0)  { 
        foreach(array_keys($array) as $key){ 
            $temp[$key] = $array[$key][$index]; 
            if ($temp[$key] == $value){ 
                $newarray[$key] = $array[$key]; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $newarray;
}
$array = /* array here */ 
$type1 = array_values(filter_by_value($array, 'type', '1'));
$type2 = array_values(filter_by_value($array, 'type', '2'));
$i = 1; $x = 1; $y = 1;
$sorted = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($i % 2) {
        $sorted[$i-1] = $type1[$x-1];
        $x++;
    } else {
        $sorted[$i-1] = $type2[$y-1];
        $y++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Found filter_by_value() on php.net but I don't remember where so, that's not made by me.
Maybe this is not the best solution but it works pretty fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom comparison function that compares the `key_1` sub-keys of each item (you can use [`strcmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) to do this conveniently). Assuming you do not want to change the *structure* of the resulting array, it would look something like this:

```
$arr = /* your array */
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['key_1'], $b['key_1']); });
```

Comment: This sorted the array like this: All first_type then all second_type. But I need it to sort like this first_type | second_type | first_type | second_type | etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, maybe arrange is more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

If `sort()` and its relevant alternatives don't work you will have to use `usort()` or `uasort()` with a custom function to sort this array.